# Python updating my variable in while loop?

Tags: python-3.x

Python is updating v0, when calculating norm_. I don't understand why this is so and it results in norm_ being 0. If I run the same code in matlab say, the code works.
'''python

```
v = array([0, 0])
norm_ = 1
n = 0
while norm_ > tol:
    v0 = v
    v[0] = max(5.0 + 0.5 * lmbda * v[0] + 0.5 * lmbda * v[1], 10.0 + lmbda * v[1])
    v[1] = -1 + lmbda * v[1]
    norm_ = norm(v - v0, inf)
    n += 1
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

As in Python every variable is a reference when you change an element of 'v' it will affect 'v0' to because it points to the same object.
 I suggest you should use copy to avoid it:

```
v0 = array([0, 0])
v = copy(v0)
norm_ = 1
n = 0
while norm_ > tol:
    v[0] = max(5.0 + 0.5 * lmbda * v[0] + 0.5 * lmbda * v[1], 10.0 + lmbda * v[1])
    v[1] = -1 + lmbda * v[1]
    norm_ = norm(v - v0, np.inf)
    n += 1
```

Comment: This is not working. Doing that results in v=(9, -1) all the time and its not true.

Answer (score 0):

`Numpy` array object, like python `list` object, is mutable container of other objects (dtype). In your snippet, in each iteration, assigning `v0 = v`, both variables are pointing to the same memory location. So mutating one of them cause the other one to change. To change this behavior, you can use `copy()` attribute:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 0])
b_1 = a
b_2 = a.copy()
print(b_1 is a)  #  True
print(b_2 is a)  #  False
```

So the final code must be:

```
v = array([0, 0])
norm_ = 1
n = 0
while norm_ > tol:
    v0 = v.copy()
    v[0] = max(5.0 + 0.5 * lmbda * v[0] + 0.5 * lmbda * v[1], 10.0 + lmbda * v[1])
    v[1] = -1 + lmbda * v[1]
    norm_ = norm(v - v0, inf)
    n += 1
```

side-note: for importing `numpy`, use `import numpy as np` as a convention. It helps you, for instance, use `norm = np.norm(...)` and make code easier to read and debug.

Comment: Well, I tried that and the output is not right for two reasons. The max should be 9.275 for v[0] and -1.95 for v[1]. Secondly, v seems to be fixed after this, it's 9 and -1 all the time, this aint right.

Comment: @Vaolter well, in the code, not `lmbda` nor `tol` are provided (also logic). But, as you mentioned it works in `matlab` I just clarified the difference between two programming languages. in the snippet you provided, `v - v0` is always zero, as described. For now, you must recheck other parts of your code.